# Why would a contributed module try to load one of its files from a custom directory?

Tags: 8, plugins

I built a module on a local instance in my module/custom directory; I then published it on drupal.org, as [Group by Field Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/group_by_field_widget). For some reason, when I install [the release 1.1.1](https://www.drupal.org/project/group_by_field_widget/releases/1.1.1) via Composer, I get this error.

> Warning: include(/app/web/modules/custom/group_by_field_widget/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/EntityReferenceGroupByFieldWidget.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /app/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
> Warning: include(): Failed opening '/app/web/modules/custom/group_by_field_widget/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/EntityReferenceGroupByFieldWidget.php' for inclusion (include_path='/app/vendor/pear/pear_exception:/app/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/app/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/app/vendor/pear/archive_tar:.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /app/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
> Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginException: Plugin (entity_reference_group_by_field_widget) instance class "Drupal\group_by_field_widget\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\EntityReferenceGroupByFieldWidget" does not exist. in Drupal\Component\Plugin\Factory\DefaultFactory::getPluginClass() (line 97 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Factory/DefaultFactory.php).

The module is installed in the *module/contrib* directory via Composer, but the warning states that /app/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php is loading files from /app/web/modules/custom/.

Please note the error only appears when editing the manage form display page.

When I move the module into the custom directory it works fine. What would tie a module to a directory?

Comment: This was resolved but no solution has been found. I renamed my widget from EntityReferenceGroupByFieldWidget to GroupByFieldReferenceWidget and like magic it started working. Still looking for reason the original version didn't work. Could it be a core restriction on how widgets are named?

Comment: Yeah, I just installed your module and I couldn't reproduce the error.  It could be that your `composer.json` on the test site was messed up somehow.  In the future, it is much easier to debug problems if you post the actual code (the `composer.json` that you used to install the module) and the version of the module that is not working.

Comment: @PatrickKenny did you install the 1.1.2 version because that is the version with the change and it does work as expected. version 1.1.1 is the broken release.

Comment: @PatrickKenny Also the error only appears when you visit the manage form display page.

Comment: I installed 1.1.2 because how am I supposed to know what version to install if you don't say?  And how am I supposed to know how to reproduce the error if you don't describe how to do so in the question?

Comment: @PatrickKenny My apologies, I was working the problem after I posted the question. I had literally just release the fix that resolved this when you downloaded it. You are correct, I should have provided better details.